# Як називається вид діяльності, якою займається оглядач?

Tags: вибір-слова

[**Огля́дач**](http://sum.in.ua/s/oghljadach) — фахівець-аналітик, який досліджує якусь проблематику і висловлює свою точку зору у друкованому виданні, радіо або ТБ.

Наприклад: *політичний огля́дач, спортивний огля́дач*.

А як назвати вид діяльності цієї особи?

Наприклад, у фразі: *За дванадцять років досвіду політичного ____ я збагнув, що…*

- *О́гляд* — не підходить, бо *огляд* — одинична дія, а не вид діяльності.
- [*Огляда́ння*](http://sum.in.ua/s/oghljadannja) — це радше процес.
- *Огля́дацтво* — такого слова я не наґуґлив.

Comment: Особисто мені зовсім не здається, що «огляд» — це одинична дія. Діяльність оглядача — огляд преси (напр.), він постійно оглядає пресу, час від часу публікує огляди, він займається оглядом преси.

Comment: Хмм... А чому Ви наголос саме на «я» поставили? СУМ-11 дозволяє обидва наголоси (на «я» і на «а»), і наголос на «а», здається, використовується значимо часто (не кажу, який частіше). Можна виправити на «[**Огля́дач** або **огляда́ч**](http://sum.in.ua/s/oghljadach) – …»?

Comment: @Sasha, +1. [Орфоепічний словник Погрібного](http://www.movi.com.ua/ukrajinski-slovniki/970-orfoepichniy-slovnik-ukrainskoyi-movi) теж допускає обидва наголоси.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, і «Культура мови на щодень» за ред. С. Я. Єрмоленко (2000, Київ, «Довіра») — теж ([1](http://kultura-movy.wikidot.com/nagolos), [2](http://flightcollege.com.ua/library/8%20ФИЛОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ%20НАУКИ/81%20ЯЗЫКОЗНАНИЕ/81.2%20УКР/Порадники/Культура%20мовы%20на%20щодень.doc)), хоч не знаю, наскільки це авторитетне джерело.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Останнім часом науковці та дослідники виокремлюють **оглядово-аналітичний** вид діяльності.

Зокрема:

> У структурі інформаційної діяльності вагоме значення належить
>   *оглядово-аналітичній* діяльності.

[Основи інформаційно-аналітичної діяльності. Захарова І.В., Філіпова Л.Я.](http://culonline.com.ua/Books/Osnovy_inform_analit_Zaharova.pdf)

> На підставі цього можлива подальша диференціація складових поняття, за
>   якої виділяється інформаційно-аналітична, *оглядово-аналітична*,
>   контрольно-аналітична  та інші види діяльності.

[Поняття та зміст аналітичної діяльності в контексті інформаційної політики, Мандзюк Олег Андрійович, голова Інституту стратегічних ініціатив Глобальної організації союзницького лідерства, кандидат юридичних наук](http://goal-int.org/ponyattya-ta-zmist-analitichnoi-diyalnosti-v-konteksti-informacijnoi-politiki/)

> 65. Пономаренко Л. Стратегічні напрями *оглядово-аналітичної* діяльності в ДНПБ України ім. В. О. Сухом­линського / Лариса
>       Пономаренко // Наукові праці Націо­нальної бібліотеки України імені В.
>       І. Вернадського.— К., 2009.— Вип. 25.— С. 36–46.

[Анотований бібліографічний покажчик літератури за 2010 рік з проблем бібліотекознавства, бібліографознав­ства та книгознавства, Львів-2010](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_F_WBpuQLxoJ:www.lsl.lviv.ua/data/2010-N2.doc+&cd=45&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua)

> *Оглядово-аналітична* діяльність. Види оглядів: бібліографічний, рефера­тивний, аналітичний, прогностичний.

[Робоча програма навчальної дисципліни «Інформаційно-аналітична діяльність у міжнародних відносинах», Терещук В. І., доцент кафедри міжнародних відносин та інформації, кандидат політичних наук, доцент](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:5jouLwEFWHcJ:library.krok.edu.ua/media/library/category/knmzd/rpnd/rpnd-0246_2015.doc+&cd=34&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua)

> У структурі інформаційно-аналітичної діяльності вагоме значення
>   належить *оглядово-аналітичній діяльності*. Мета цього напряму -
>   інформаційне забезпечення управлінських рішень і створення системи
>   інформаційної підтримки базової діяльності користувачів інформації.

[Інформаційно-аналітична діяльність. Варенко В.М.](http://megalib.com.ua/content/1913_26_Harakteristika_osnovnih_riznovidiv_IAD.html)

Утім, **варто зазначити**, що окремі діячі, наприклад, Олександр Карпенко, завідувач відділу Державної науково-педагогічної бібліотеки України імені В. О. Сухомлинського, кандидат наук з державного управління, вважають таке вирізнення [штучним](http://dnpb.smart.biz.ua/datas/upload/files/351716413.pdf) і [недоцільним](http://dnpb.smart.biz.ua/datas/upload/files/847500115.pdf).

Comment: Ви даремно не узагальнили всі ті цитати, з них же якийсь висновок випливає. Звісно, що кожен може свій висновок скласти, та ви навіть не уявляєте, як усім цікаво почути саме ваш висновок. ;)

Comment: @YellowSky, хм, невже фраза "Останнім часом науковці та дослідники виокремлюють оглядово-аналітичний вид діяльності" не тягне на мій *узагальнений висновок"? ;)

Comment: З огляду на ту полеміку, яка розгорнулася тут у коментах, то таки не тягне. Я б тепер написав иншу відповідь, яка б вкючала в себе конструктивні пропозиції Sasha, та от я не знаю, чи це етично давати дві розбіжні відповіді на одне й те саме питання. Я б дуже хотів, аби Sasha сам все це написав як відповідь.

Comment: @YellowSky, спочатку я схилялась до Вашої точки зору, що **огляд** може бути видом діяльності. Потім Sasha навів аргументи, що мене переконали. Тим паче, трапились підтвердження. Не стала виокремлювати *оглядову* діяльність, бо, хоч теоретично й можна виділити, зважаючи на написання *оглядово-аналітичний* через дефіс, та підтверджень тому в наукових чи, бодай, методичних джерелах не знайшла.

Comment: Боюся, що це не зовсім те, про що я хотів запитати, але неточно сформулював (хотів одним словом і на зразок `-цтво`). Тому мушу прийняти цю відповідь, бо провина — моя.

Comment: @bytebuster, мабуть, чекали підтвердження для *оглядацтво*? Мене теж ваше запитання, а радше дискусія в коментарях з подальшими пошуками, спонукали до зміни думки, всупереч власним очікуванням щодо *огляду*.

Answer (score 3):

Особисто мені зовсім не здається, що «огляд» — це одинична дія. Діяльність оглядача — огляд преси (напр.), він постійно оглядає пресу, час від часу публікує огляди, він займається оглядом преси. [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/oghljad): «Огляд — Дія за значенням оглядати».

Comment: СУМ не стверджує, що *огляд* — то одининна дія. Але й, на жаль, не стверджує, що *огляд* може бути видом діяльності. Було б добре підібрати пару цитат, що позначають словом «огляд» саме вид постійної/періодичної діяльності (професію, хобі тощо).

Comment: Може, щось типу такого: «[cпелеотурист — турист, який займається *оглядом*, вивченням печер](http://slovnyk.sum.in.ua/s/speleoturyst)»; «[підготовка персоналу експлуатанта, який займається *оглядом* (вантажу та пасажирів) з метою забезпечення безпеки](http://www.avia.gov.ua/uploads/documents/7571.doc)»; «[Михайло займається *оглядом* та випуском аналітичних звітів щодо банківського сектору України](https://voxukraine.org/item/mihajlo-demkiv/)»?

Comment: От наприклад «тур» позначає окрему дію; так само «операція». Ми не можемо сказати «Михайло займається туром/операцією»; точніше можемо, але це позначатиме, що від відповідає за *конкретний* тур чи операцію, а не що це його вид діяльності в цілому. Щоб позначити вид діяльності в цілому, ми скажемо «Михайло займається тур**ами** / операці**ями**» (в множині). А от «займається оглядом»/«відповідає за огляд» двозначне — може позначати як «ось цей ось огляд, що зараз триває», так і вид діяльності. Ми не мусимо для речення про вид діяльності ставити огляд у множину (отже огляд — не лише окрема дія).

Comment: @Sasha У словниках не знайшла цього значення, а от у Вікіпедії є стаття [**Огляд (журналістика)**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4_(%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)), де **огляд** тлумачиться ще і як *жанр* з посиланнями на джерела. Я теж, як і Yellow Sky, схиляюсь до думки, що може використовуватися і як *вид діяльності*. Принаймні, заперечень щодо цього я не зустрічала.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, якщо чесно, мені здається, що жанри ближче якраз до одиничних дій, а не до видів діяльності. Типу, хтось щось робить (наприклад, оглядає, доповідає, усміхається), і потім письмово оформлений спосіб-чи-результат дії називають тим же словом, що й одиничну дію («огляд» — це є значення СУМ-11 під номером 5, по-моєму; «доповідь»; «[усмішка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Усмішка_(література))»)

Comment: @Sasha, [ЖАНР, у, чол.](http://sum.in.ua/s/zhanr) "3. Спосіб що-небудь робити; сукупність прийомів; стиль, манера." Не впевнена, але *робити*, *стиль*, *манера*, здається, тяжіють до повторюваних дій, а не одноразової. Можливо, помиляюсь.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, так, **за суттю**, жанр — це саме повторювана дія (її стиль, манера); але **називають** жанри, як правило тими словами, що одиничну дію («доповідь», «усмішка»), а не вид діяльності; отака дивина виходить.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, тобто я що хотів сказати — з існування дії *А* і жанру *А* необов'язково випливає, що слово «*А*» може позначати вид діяльності. Приклади: «усмішка» (дія — так, жанр — так, діяльність — ні), «доповідь» (дія — так, жанр — так, діяльність — ні); ми не можемо сказати «він професійно займається усмішкою/доповіддю» (хіба що «усмішками/доповідями»).

Comment: @Sasha, makes sense. Ось ще знайшла [Основи інформаційно-аналітичної діяльності - Захарова І.В.](http://westudents.com.ua/glavy/27796-61-oglyad-yak-rezultat-oglyadovo-analtichno-dyalnost-funkts-oglyadu.html), де **огляд** розглядається як результат *оглядово-аналітичної діяльності*. Тобто, діяльність може бути *оглядовою*?

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, так. І це тягне на окрему відповідь, по-моєму. Типу, оглядач займається **оглядов[о-аналіличн]ою діяльністю**. (Цей термін не має невизначенності «одинична дія чи діяльність».)

Comment: @Sasha, ["Огляд торговельної політики членів СОТ – це один із найважливіших видів діяльності організації..."](http://www.me.gov.ua/News/Detail?lang=uk-UA&id=ce60ac5e-75ae-4051-8aac-9022cd3abb27&title=UZheneviRozpochavsiaPershiiOgliadTorgovelnoiPolitikiUkrainiVRamkakhSot) Складно все з цим **оглядом**) Хоча варіант *оглядової діяльності* мені імпонує.

Comment: І ще я не впевнена, що в МЕРТ цей допис готував фахівець,що знається на таких тонкощах. Цікаво також почути думку автора запитання щодо нашого обговорення.